# display time and date in GMT or UTC

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am trying to display GMT/UTC time with current date LIVE
i can display current time with it will be fixed until  did refresh for the page

what i need to do display the time and date in UTC/GMT in my page as PHP or java code

thank you

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question as it's not easy to understand what you are looking for. That said my understanding is that you want to display the time (a clock?) on client side with the exact time? Then you should likely have something that update your html every x seconds with a new js date that you could format thanks to libraries as moment (npm package)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to convert your current time to another timezone lets say GMT or UTC then you can follow the following steps for javascript:
You can use `moment-timezone` lib.

```
const moment = require('moment-timezone')
const now = moment().format()
moment.tz(now, 'UTC').format()
moment.tz(now, 'GMT').format()
```